# Loading initial schema into Flyway table for existing database

Tags: flyway

I have read through the Flyway (2.1.1) documentation, and I just wanted to get a little clarification on one point...

I dumped the current DDL from our production db into a file, V1__baseddl.sql.
I verified that our QA database has a schema which matched production.

I now want to put our QA database under Flyway management (followed by production). We are using Flyway via the API.
I called flyway.setInitVersion(1), then flyway.init(), and I was expecting it to find the V1__baseddl.sql file, and set that as version 1 in the flyway.schema_version table, but not actually execute its contents (since the schema already exists in the database). In the schema_version table, I am seeing a row for the initial version, but for script, it just has << Flyway Init >>.

How can I "load" the initial schema file (V1__baseddl.sql) into the schema_version table as version 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the description, you have to call `flyway.setInitDescription("baseddl")`

Comment: and will that actually look at the file itself (generate the hash, etc)?

Comment: No, there will be no file lookup and no hash. The main purpose is that wenn V2 comes along it can be migrated equally on all environments (and to ensure V1 doesn't get executed in the ones you inited)